# pre-CanActivate or pre-CanLoad on deep links

Tags: angular, session, coldfusion, angular2-routing

I am tasked with replacing existing Adobe Flash & Flex applications running on a ColdFusion 11 backend with Angular applications.

The assumption is that the user will be logged in and have a session already before they are even able to get to the Angular application pages, and I am not allowed to request a new logon by the user, or make them click on additional links to make their deep links work.

I have a SessionService created which obtains the Coldfusion session variables successfully and stores them in a Session model.

It is my intention, based on the existing application architecture, that we will be implementing lazy loading of feature modules.

My problem lies in the fact that I need to obtain data from the ColdFusion session to validate that the user is authorized to even view the feature before I even attempt to load the feature, and since 99%, or more, of the access will come from deep links into the feature modules, it is not guaranteed that the session service will have been called yet.

Route resolvers appear to occur after the Route guards in the sequence of events, so I am struggling with how to ensure the CanLoad guards have access to successfully loaded Session model from the SessionService.

EDIT: Clarification below....

The canLoad depends on values from the session and privilege levels that must be checked based on what page they are going to.

For example....the deep linked page is a page that views details about a unit

http://url/app/feature/childFeature?unitId=123&orderId=456

The session user needs to be assigned to that particular unitId and must have viewAccess privilege to that childFeature, which is defined in a table in the database

So, I need to know the URL parameter 'unitId' while on the canLoad guard, which I don't believe I have access to on the Route??? and then I need to do a logical AND with the results of the viewAccess privilege check and return that back as the result of the canLoad.

Any guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `canLoad` determines if a module listed in path can be loaded or not, like if you say `path: ':id' ` you can decide if a user can access this path or not, But if you want to stop on values of id it wont be possible. If you are willing to hard code the routes like `path: '123'` it can be achieved, you may also consider updating Route configuration dynamically so adding all possible routes at run time based upon some configuration which will insert hard coded routes, Cheers!!

Comment: Also it seems you have access to `unitId` in other component from where you will be routing, so  What you can try is storing this value in some service variable may be be in your session service while clicking on link and accessing it in the `canLoad` gurad.

Comment: Can't assume that the user hasn't bookmarked the link previously

Comment: So what I am gathering here, is that it is pointless to use a canLoad guard, and instead do validation of privileges and assignment in the loaded component.

Comment: Not really, you can extract the validation part in a component which can be  pre loaded, and decide to load child modules based upon that. and even the user has bookmarked the link, its very easy to get the Route param from Router events to use it in canLoad, Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try below,

In your `SessionService`, create a Subject which will emit once your session Model has been loaded,

**SessionService**

```
sessionLoaded: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();


somemethodAfterSessionisLoaded(){
   .... 
   this.sessionLoaded.next(true);
}
```

**canLoad Feature Child Module**

```
constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}

canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.sessionService.sessionLoaded;
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I added some clarification at the bottom of the original post.  I think that might muddy up the possibilities some more.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer I needed.  Thanks :)